# Understanding LongWritable in Hive UDFs

Tags: java, hive, schema, user-defined-functions

I tried googling it but i don't understand the documentation much. Can anyone explain what this line of code does.

It's part of a Hive UDF. I don't fully understand LongWritable or what 1L means.

```
public class CustomUDF extends UDF {
    public LongWritable evaluate(Text schema) { // what is Text schema??
        if (schema == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return new LongWritable(1l); // what does this do??
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // catch error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Hive UDFs and I'm having trouble understanding this method. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- LongWritable Class

Hadoop needs to be able to serialise data in and out of Java types via DataInput and DataOutputobjects (IO Streams usually). The Writable classes do this by implementing two methods `write(DataOuput) and readFields(DataInput). Specifically LongWritable is a Writable class that wraps a java long.

Reference - [https://www.edureka.co/community/29194/understanding-longwritable#:~:text=Hadoop%20needs%20to%20be%20able,that%20wraps%20a%20java%20long](https://www.edureka.co/community/29194/understanding-longwritable#:%7E:text=Hadoop%20needs%20to%20be%20able,that%20wraps%20a%20java%20long).

For other classes of same type - https://blog.dataiku.com/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf

'evaluate' method is the entry point for udf. So if you call udf in Hive as 'select myudf('aa')' then input 'aa' will be passed to your evaluate method. (We can also overload this method, according to the use case)

Now coming to your code. First of all this code contains error since if it goes to catch it will not return anything. But let us assume that if input is not null, it will return a new LongWritable(1L). Then this code will

- return null if null is passed to your udf. Hive command - select myudf(null)
- If nothing is passed to udf, it will give error stating that no matching method found in this class, since in this case it will look for the evaluate method which doesn't take any arguments. Hive command - select myudf();
- If you pass anything in your udf that could be converted to Text, then it will return 1(long). Hive command - select myudf('aa');

Also, the difference between 1 and 1L is that 1 is of int type and 1L is of long type.